# smart taskscheduler with loadbalancing

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task

we are trying  to move from timer that run every couple of seconds and process the incoming data to some kind of threadpool methodology.

i have found this link [link](http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/32787)

and i know there is TPL with taskscheduler.

its need to be smart of course because we handle a lot and i mean a lot of incoming data.

can you please direct me to a good ref of learning book article or open source code, that implement that.

any help will be grateful.
Guy

**update:** the data is coming from our client via wcf service enters the db and the main process (the one with the timer) process the data

Comment: Where is the data coming from?  If the data is from, say, Socket I/O, then there are well-known patterns for receiving and processing the data that make efficient use of threading resources.

Comment: the data is coming from our client via wcf service enters the db and the main process (the one with the timer) process the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a brilliant book on all flavours of Windows Multithreading, Joe Duffy has an excellent book [Concurrent Programming on Windows](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Concurrent-Programming-Windows-Architecture-Development/dp/032143482X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1302642932&sr=8-1).  For further information on TPL another great book [Pro .NET 4.0 Parallel Programming in C#](http://www.amazon.co.uk/NET-Parallel-Programming-Experts-Voice/dp/1430229675/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1302643049&sr=1-1).

Together these books should set you up very well to produce robust scalable multithreaded solutions, they are very knowledgable guys!  Good luck.